# Best way to resign and my rights.?(I LIVE IN CANADA)

Tags: resignation, termination, health, sickness, canada

I'm on sick leave for 4 months and I'm not ready to go back to work for many reasons. In October I was having issues with my neck and my ankles that were sore. I was told in a letter that my health was getting in the way of my duties and they had to make me a new position. They implied that I should take the new "job" or get terminated. I was given a new position where I could not work overtime, worked on my own..same salary/benefits. They stopped me from doing a particular duty which I know was never done by anyone else. I think they stopped that duty..meaning our department doesn't get paid from third party insurers. Not my issue anymore.

I then got sick (probably from stress ) and my doctor got sick and she quit in 24 hours. I ended up in hospital and after trying to get better I felt I was good to go back to work or do the paper work no one bothered to do. I was called into a meeting with two of my bosses and said they are putting me on sick leave.

I didn't ask for it...they said if I feel better they would take me back after two months...I have EI sick leave pay til June. I'm still not well 
Physically and emotionally. I sensed they were preferring to hire younger staff..(I am 44). I was never included into important meetings and asked to be and they shrugged me off. I asked if they received certain emails and they said maybe, or probably ended up in spam.

My clients love me and miss me as I pop into work to pick up stuff or purchase stuff (because i get a discount). I am in tears almost because both myself and a few clients have been part of the organization for 20 years.

I have 3 choices:

- resign and try to apply for regular EI;
- try applying for group LTD (looks dismal because i have too many pre-existing conditions);
- quit and apply for CPP. I don't want to dip into my RRSP..

Any suggestions by anybody who has had experience with something like this? I have about a week to decide as I see my Doc next week.

Answer (score 7):

Resigning is rarely the best solution. Resigning means "I don't want to work anymore". It is almost always better to wait for your company to lay you off. If your company lays you off, you will most likely get some unemployment benefits. By resigning, you may give up your rights to any such benefits.

You said you have three choices, all involving resigning. You have the choice not to resign, which is most likely the better choice.

Your most important duty is to yourself, your health, and your income. You have been ill, you haven't been able to do the work that you were hired for. You seem to think that your company is against you, because they took your work away, you "sense" they want someone younger, and you feel everything stressful.

I see things differently: Your company found that you couldn't do your job due to health reasons, which are none of your fault. The company didn't fire you, which they might have done, but gave you an easier position, with no overtime, that should have been easier for you, paying the same salary. You seem to see that as a punishment, I see this as someone looking after you and trying to make sure that you get well. Where you "sense" that they want someone younger, I think you see everyone as being against you, which is quite likely not true.

You have two months to get better. Don't stress out, relax, use the time to get better, and don't do anything stupid like resigning.